# Seat booking using synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, grails, concurrency, grails-orm

I am trying to implement seat booking validation using a synchronized block like this:

```
synchronized(this) {
    int seatsBooked = GrantAssessment.countByExamSessionAndExamDateBetweenAndIsCancelled(examSession,now,now+1,false)
    int seatsRemaining = examSession.maxSeat - seatsBooked
    if(seatsRemaining<1){
        throw new CustomValidationException("All seats booked...")
    }

    // assign assessment which increases countByExam... query count by 1
    grantAssessment = assignAssessment(examCommerce,examSession,examDate,identificationType,idNumber)
}
```

assignAssessment() method code is as follows:

```
def assignAssessment(ExamCommerce examCommerce, ExamSession examSession,Date examDate,IdentificationType identificationType,String idNumber) {
    .................
    examSession.addToGrantAssessmentList(grantAssessment)
    ..............................
    grantAssessment.save(failOnError: true,flush: true)
    examSession.save(failOnError: true,flush: true)
    return grantAssessment
}
```

When I hit using browser 1(different thread) it enters the synchornized block and assigns a seat. When browser 2(thread 2, almost same time) enters the block the query count returned by the code below :

```
     GrantAssessment.countByExamSessionAndExamDateBetweenAndIsCancelled(examSession,now,now+1,false)
```

is same.But the same thread shows reduced value(correct) after synchronized block.

Due to this, both the threads assigns the seat even if totalSeat is equal to 1.

How to handle to concurrency such that availableSeats value should be calculated correctly in a synchronized way. Is JMS OK for such scenarios ?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using different monitors.
For example the following can lead to the same state as you described `both the threads assigns the seat even if totalSeat is equal to 1.`

```
private static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

boolean bookTwoSeatsInParallel() {
    Future<Integer> res1 = executorService.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            synchronized(this) {
                //your seat booking code which returns seat num or whatever
            }
            return -1;
        }
    });

    Future<Integer> res2 = executorService.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            synchronized(this) {
                //your seat booking code which returns seat num or whatever
            }
            return -1;
        }
    });
}
```

`res1.get().equals(res2.get())` could be true. This example is a bit redundant but it shows the case when different threads use different monitors in a try to achieve valid synchronized state.

To fix this you should synchronize on *the same monitor*, like this

```
private static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
private final Object bookingMonitor = new Object();

boolean bookTwoSeatsInParallel() {
    Future<Integer> res1 = executorService.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            synchronized(bookingMonitor) {
                //your seat booking code which returns seat num or whatever
            }
            return -1;
        }
    });

    Future<Integer> res2 = executorService.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            synchronized(bookingMonitor) {
                //your seat booking code which returns seat num or whatever
            }
            return -1;
        }
    });
}
```

Note that all variables you read/modify inside the `synchronized(this) {...}` block shouldn't be read/modified from somewhere else without synchronization on the same monitor. In other case it can lead to [Thread Interference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html) and [Memory Consistency Errors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html)

---

> Is JMS OK for such scenarios ?

Definitely you can use JMS, pass booking requests through it to the only worker thread. But you don't need such a complex solution for this simple case.

Comment: I was able to fix it using pessimistic locking. I simply used examSession = ExamSession.lock(ID) in the beginning and the other thread waited till the transaction ended. Is it ok ?

Comment: Also, why did you repeat the same code twice. ? There can be many people  booking a seat simultaneously.(Not just 2)

Comment: I repeated it twice in `bookTwoSeatsInParallel()` function just for example, which you can easily run many times in a for loop of main method and make sure that this code really contains an error. Pessimistic locking is fine, but it brings some extra overhead (which in usually unnoticeable). So it depends on a workload inside your application.